# Google Maps Route Generation with Waypoints

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got an existing app that tracks vehicles and renders their polyline on a map, and I want to be able to import these polylines into another app using the routing service (so that the imported polyline snaps to the road and can be dragged around etc).

What I'm currently doing is encoding:

```
var encoded_path = google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(coordinate_array)
```

The lat lng coordinates array that draws the line (inside the polyline app), and passing this into the directions service route like so (inside the other app):

```
var coordinates = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encoded_path);

var request = {
   origin: coordinates[0],
   destination: coordinates[coordinates.length - 1],
   travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};

MapService.directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      MapService.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
   }
});
```

The problem with this approach is that it's only using the start and end of the polyline to draw the route, so all of the diversions along the route are not shown. So I tried to add waypoints (Google has a limit of 8) to try and get a slightly more accurate route like so:

```
var waypoints = [];

if (coordinates.length <= 8) {
   waypoints = coordinates;
}
else {
   for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      var index = Math.floor((coordinates.length/8) * i);

      // Break if there's no more waypoints to be added
      if (index > coordinates.length - 1)
         break;

      waypoints.push(new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[index].lat(), coordinates[index].lng()));

      // Break if we've just added the last waypoint
      if (index == coordinates.length - 1)
         break;
   }
}
```

This way it gets waypoints evenly across the coordinates array. And then I'm trying to display them like so on my call to route:

```
var request = {
   origin: coordinates[0],
   destination: coordinates[coordinates.length - 1],
   waypoints: waypoints
   travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};
```

But I'm getting this error: Error: in property waypoints: at index 0: unknown property lb

Does anyone know what could be happening, or how to do this waypoint stuff? I can confirm that the array is correctly generated through the console, here's an example of the first array element:

```
Array[8]
  0: N
    lb: -22.39019
    mb: 143.04560000000004
    __prot__: N
  1:...etc etc
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> waypoints.push(new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[index].lat(), coordinates[index].lng()));

the 'waypoints' property of the DirectionsRequest object definition should be an Array of google.maps.DirectionsWaypoint object definitions https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#DirectionsWaypoint

So, try:

```
waypoints.push(
    {
        location: new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[index].lat(), coordinates[index].lng())
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you, you were correct. I also needed stopover: false, but you weren't to know that because it was a specific of my app.

Comment: Further to that, turns out this actually doesn't work. It worked if I used an encoded path that was generated by drawing a route using the route service, but passing in coordinates from a polyline as waypoints causes the entire route not to render (presumably because some of the coordinates might be slightly off the road). I was hoping Google would just snap it to the closest valid coordinate but I guess not.